# Linking standard library MSVC fails, MinGW works

Tags: linker, llvm, llvm-ir, unresolved-external

So I have the following LLVM IR file:

```
@msg = global [24 x i8] c"Hello LLVM!"

declare i32 @puts(i8* %string)

define void @main() {
"entry block":
    %0 = getelementptr [24 x i8], [24 x i8]* @msg, i32 0, i32 0
    %1 = call i32 @puts(i8* %0)
    ret void
}
```

I then turn that into an .obj file using llc. If I try to link the standard library (for the puts function) it works fine use the MinGW lib:

```
link /ENTRY:main /DEFAULTLIB:libmsvcrt.a /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OUT:bin/program.exe bin/program.obj
```

But using the MSVC library it fails:

```
link /ENTRY:main /DEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\amd64" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OUT:bin/program.exe bin/program.obj 

program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol puts referenced in function main
bin/program.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here and hope someone here can help.

Comment: Find out which MS library the put function is in, where it is located and add it to your libpath

Comment: Also, are you sure it is not `_puts` vs. `puts`?

Comment: Puts should be correct based on MSDN and some other LLVM Hello world examples. Puts is in every version of the C runtime library according to MSDN, the msvcrt.lib is located in that filepath. It's the x64 too, so that shouldn't be the issue either.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally managed to find the issue, though I'm still not sure why it didn't work. The solution for me was linking ucrt.lib which is a different version of the C runtime library. But on MSDN they stated that any version would work with puts. I figured it out by making a small "hello world" in C in Visual Studio and turning on /VERBOSE:lib to see what they link.

Comment: That is why I said to find out where, I knew it did move somewhere and couldn't remember which lib. Glad you found it.